# How to contact Microsoft Windows Development Team?

Tags: windows

How to contact Microsoft Windows development team to suggest a new functionality to bring to Microsoft Windows OS ?

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/27932/windows-10-send-us-feedback. Or just google for "Microsoft feedback"

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft has some [forums associated with TechNet](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/home). While this is primarily a user-to-user support area - much like StackExchange - Microsoft do have people monitoring them, and occasionally chiming in with 'official' answers. I've also seen people post feature requests to the relevant subfora; whether MS takes those into account is an unanswered question at this time.